# Fill Target audience field in a list using PowerShell - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, splistitem, audience-targeting

I need to set target audience field in a list while populating the list with data.
How can I achieve this using PowerShell command.

I found this [article](http://www.reality-tech.com/programmatically-targetting-audiences-for-audience-enabled-libraries-in-sharepoint/). But it didn't worked as it throws

> `Column 'Target Audiences' does not exist. It may have been deleted by
>   another user.`

But `Target audiences` field is there when I inspect from list settings.

Here is the sample code I used :

```
$SiteUrl = "SiteUrl"
$listName = "ListName"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $SiteUrl 
$list=$spWeb.lists[$listName]
$dataCount = 100
$targetAudience = "newusers"
    if($list -ne $null)
    {
      write-host -f green $listName "List exists. Now Populating data."
        for($i=0; $i -lt $dataCount; $i++)
        {
             $newItem = $list.Items.Add()
             $randomCatg = "data"          
             $newItem["Menu Category"] = "data"
             $newItem["MenuItem"] = "data"
             $newItem["Date"] = "data"
             $newItem["Target Audiences"] = $targetAudience
             $newItem.Update() 
        }
        $list.Update()
    }
```

**Update :**
    Then I set the target audience field as below by referring this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030991/set-target-audiences-field-with-multiple-values-on-a-list-item)
`$newItem[$newItem.Fields["Target Audiences"].InternalName] = $targetAudience`
but still not solved

Is this really possible or am I doing it in the wrong way?

Comment: It worked after I restarted the Sharepoint server. I don't know what the reason is but it worked after restarting.